# Listing packages in Yum that depend on another installed package

Tags: package-management, rhel, yum

I am trying to install a 3rd-party RPM package on RHEL5 which depends on version 3.4 of sqlite. According to Yum I already have 3.3.6 installed.

Is there a way to list the installed packages that depend on sqlite 3.3.6?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The rpm option you want is:

```
rpm -q --whatrequires sqlite
```

**Edited: added --installed per discussion in other answers/comments**

**Edited: removed --installed as it is an invalid option for rpm**

Comment: Further, `repoquery` can be used to generate a nice tree like structure of all packages that require a particular package, for example: `repoquery  --pkgnarrow=installed --tree-whatrequires sqlite`

Comment: I don't agree that this answer is reliable - certainly not on CentOS 7.x . To test, install ImageMagick. OpenEXR-libs will also be installed as ImageMagick depends on it. Now run rpm -q --whatrequires OpenEXR-libs and the return is "no package requires OpenEXR-libs" which is INCORRECT. Now run "repoquery -q --installed --whatrequires OpenEXR-libs" and it correctly returns "ImageMagick-0:6.7.8.9-15.el7_2.x86_64". @just a random guy's answer below should be the correct answer here.

Comment: `--installed` is an option for `repoquery` but is invalid for `rpm`.

Comment: I *think* that rpm -q only reports package dependencies and not library (*.so) dependencies.

Answer (score 82):

## Answer

```
repoquery -q --installed --whatrequires sqlite
```

## Explanations

There is another command, `rpm -q --whatrequires sqlite`, but it doesn't really work since it only reports dependencies on package names.

On the contrary, `repoquery` also looks for non-explicit dependencies. Excerpt from manpage:

```
   --alldeps
          When used with --whatrequires, look for non-explicit dependencies in addition to explicit ones (e.g. files and Provides  in  addition  to  package  names).
          This is the default.
```

#### Example

Let's take package `libdb`.

```
# rpm -q --whatrequires libdb
no package requires libdb
```

If we trust `rpm`, no package depends on `libdb` so we should be able to remove it smoothly. However...

```
# yum remove -y libdb
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libdb.x86_64 0:5.3.21-19.el7 will be erased
--> Processing Dependency: libdb(x86-64) = 5.3.21-19.el7 for package: libdb-utils-5.3.21-19.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdb-5.3.so()(64bit) for package: pam-1.1.8-12.el7_1.1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdb-5.3.so()(64bit) for package: rpm-4.11.3-17.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdb-5.3.so()(64bit) for package: rpm-libs-4.11.3-17.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdb-5.3.so()(64bit) for package: libdb-utils-5.3.21-19.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdb-5.3.so()(64bit) for package: cyrus-sasl-lib-2.1.26-20.el7_2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdb-5.3.so()(64bit) for package: rpm-python-4.11.3-17.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdb-5.3.so()(64bit) for package: python-libs-2.7.5-39.el7_2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdb-5.3.so()(64bit) for package: rpm-devel-4.11.3-17.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdb-5.3.so()(64bit) for package: 2:postfix-2.10.1-6.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdb-5.3.so()(64bit) for package: rpm-build-libs-4.11.3-17.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdb-5.3.so()(64bit) for package: iproute-3.10.0-54.el7_2.1.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
. . .
. . .
. . .
Error: Trying to remove "systemd", which is protected
Error: Trying to remove "yum", which is protected
```

As you can see some other packages were depending not directly on package `libdb`, but on file `libdb-5.3.so()(64bit)` provided by it.

Finally, when using `repoquery` we get the real list of packages depending on `libdb`:

```
# repoquery -q --installed --whatrequires libdb
cyrus-sasl-lib-0:2.1.26-20.el7_2.x86_64
iproute-0:3.10.0-54.el7_2.1.x86_64
libdb-utils-0:5.3.21-19.el7.x86_64
pam-0:1.1.8-12.el7_1.1.x86_64
postfix-2:2.10.1-6.el7.x86_64
python-libs-0:2.7.5-39.el7_2.x86_64
rpm-0:4.11.3-17.el7.x86_64
rpm-build-libs-0:4.11.3-17.el7.x86_64
rpm-devel-0:4.11.3-17.el7.x86_64
rpm-libs-0:4.11.3-17.el7.x86_64
rpm-python-0:4.11.3-17.el7.x86_64
```

Comment: This answer is better than the accepted answer

Comment: If `repoquery` command doesn't exist try `yum install yum-utils`

Answer (score 19):

For dnf (new version of yum) you may try with [repoquery](https://dnf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_ref.html#repoquery-command-label) wrapper command:

```sh
dnf repoquery --whatrequires sqlite
```

If it is not available you may install it with command:

```sh
dnf -y install dnf-plugins-core
```

Comment: You need `--installed --recursive` at the end so it only returns what's actually installed and doesn't pull from the repositories

Answer (score 7):

You could also try this command out.

```
repoquery --whatrequires sqlite
```

I got this command from [ServerFault](https://superuser.com/questions/294662/how-to-get-list-of-dependencies-of-non-installed-rpm-package) and also from [The Fedora Forums.](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showpost.php?p=1523686&postcount=6)

Comment: This returned packages I didn't have installed.

Comment: As @Hashbrown mentioned, add --installed at the end.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you really want to know is "what are the packages which require sqlite-3.3.6, but won't be happy with sqlite-3.4.z" ... and the only good way of finding that out, is to try it. Like:

```
echo | yum upgrade sqlite
```

Answer (score 1):

As [Wes Hardaker said](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/14601/153578), a good built-in method is by using `rpm -q --whatrequires <package>`. The thing is, `rpm` operates on *capabilities* for dependency resolution, not just simply on packages, as e.g. `dpkg` does in the Debian/Ubuntu family of Linux distributions. As others have noted, simply doing `rpm -q --whatrequires sqlite` doesn't tell the whole story, hence why some suggested using `repoquery`. `repoquery`, however, isn't installed by default in RHEL/CentOS 7 minimal (maybe desktop too?), so it may not be available for everyone.

A user can do `rpm -q --provides <pkgname>` to see all the capabilities a package provides, then use `rpm -q --whatrequires <capability>` to see what installed packages require that capability. This info can be succinctly queried using a BASH one-liner (separated here into two lines for length):

```
capabilities=($(rpm -q --provides sqlite | awk -F= '{print $1}'));
for c in "${capabilities[@]}"; do rpm -q --whatrequires "$c"; done
```

This only uses options built-in to `rpm` itself, and so it doesn't require installing any additional packages (e.g. `yum-utils` in CentOS 7, which is the package that contains `repoquery`).

Comment: Was using this a while ago, and came across a specific instance - installed `docker-compose` (via epel) in Centos7 - using the above to figure out what depends on python3-pip, and it only included python3 (which was expected).  However, further recursion on python3 (now answer, "what is removed if you remove `python3-pip`"), and everything that relied on python was also included (due to `python(abi) = 3.6` line, I think).  So take the results with a grain of salt :)  Things get _weird_ when you get to "base" capabilities (like python)