# RPM dependency conflict between libX11 and libxcb

Tags: centos, rpm, dependencies

I have to install some packages for a vnc server on a CentOS 6.5 machine that has no access to repos (so I have to transfer the rpm packages I need using sftp).

As I tried to install the package libX11-1.6.0-6 I got the following error :

> error: Failed dependencies:
>     libxcb < 1.9.1-3 conflicts with libX11-1.6.0-6.el6.i686

So I upgraded libxcb to the requested version but I still got the same error.
I tried to force the libX11 install with --nodeps but now I don't have the following libraries : libxcb-glx.so.0 and libxcb.so.1.

Trying to reinstall, upgrade or downgrade libxcb to get the libraries back has proven unsuccessful.

What shall I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The messages told you that `libxcb` conflicted with `libX11`.  The latter can be self-contained, or (in the case of your conflicting packages) using `libxcb` to replace *part* of `libX11`.  Doing that requires a different package for `libX11`.

The likely scenario is by mixing packages from different repositories as in this discussion: *[I can not update centos 6.6. Error: Package: and duplicated](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=54068).*  In it, someone had attempted to force their system to use packages from a different repository (perhaps the same as your situation).

If you really need the alternate repository, the only route forward would be to replace *all* of the packages which ultimately depend upon `libxcb` (the `libX11`, packages depending on *it*, and so forth).  Otherwise your system is inconsistent and will break in unexpected ways (such as not being able to upgrade).

To do this, you have to start by finding the dependant packages:

- [Listing packages in Yum that depend on another installed package](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14589/listing-packages-in-yum-that-depend-on-another-installed-package) (useful if you have a system which has working repositories for both sets of repositories)
- [Re: Query all dependent packages](https://www.redhat.com/archives/rpm-list/2004-February/msg00135.html) mentions two options for `rpm` (`--whatrequires` and `--whatprovides`) which you can use for analyzing the broken system).

Comment: For the sake of stability I had to cancel the installation of the vnc server as I couldn't mix packages from different repos. For the missing libraries I simply retrived them from another CentOS server and I recreated the missing links. Despite everything thank you for the reply