# Which program uses which package?

Tags: files, yum, monitoring, dependencies

Updating my Linux server is mostly a stressed part for me. Like today. With yum update i see a new version of NodeJS, but from what i can remember nodejs has been used by a program which needs to be carefully altered.

So i thought, there should be a command how to find out which program is using NodeJS, but unfortunately I can't find such command.

Is there a yum command which tells me who is using NodeJS on my system? So i can check if it is ok to update?

Comment: If everything you care about is installed through yum then you [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14589/listing-packages-in-yum-that-depend-on-another-installed-package) should cover your, if you manually installed other packages though, this won't help with them

Comment: Problem is indeed that it's about self compiled programs :(

Answer (score 1):

If the other programs are installed as RPM packages then you can see which ones require `nodejs`:

```
rpm -q --whatrequires nodejs
```

If the other programs aren't installed as RPM packages then there's no easy way. Dependency information is one of the major benefits of using a package manager, as opposed to just copying files around.

You can set up logging whenever `/usr/bin/nodejs` is executing and run your system for a few days to see what executes it. If the file is used as a script interpreter via a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) line, you can use the [audit subsystem](http://people.redhat.com/sgrubb/audit/):

```
auditctl -w /usr/bin/nodejs
```

and watch `/var/log/audit/audit.log`. If `nodejs` is called explicitly then this won't tell you what program executed it, but this does log the first few command line parameters, which hopefully includes a script path that would be enough information for you. Watch [Monitoring what program calls an executable file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/304896/monitoring-what-program-calls-an-executable-file) for other solutions.

Alternatively, if you have an idea where that program is stored, you can search for the string `nodejs`. But this is likely to return a lot of false positives (e.g. documentation files).

Comment: Thank you...can't upvote you yet, but thanks anyway.